# How to change the learning rate in PyTorch (1.6)

Tags: pytorch, learning-rate

I am using PyTorch and I want to change the learning rate after some epochs.

However, the code that is provided on most documentations, which is:

```
  optimizer = torch.optim.Adam([
        dict(params=model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate),
    ])
   #This line specifically
   optimizer.params_group[0]['lr'] = learning_rate
```

does not work.

Actually PyCharm hints at it:

> Unresolved attribute reference 'params_group' for class 'Adam'

As a result, the error thrown is:

> AttributeError: 'Adam' object has no attribute 'params_group'

How should one manually change the learning rate in PyTorch (1.6)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it is `param_groups`. You have a typo.

Comment: What a silly one. Been following some tutorial and I haven't even noticed.

Comment: Please provide the answer below so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Param_groups is not the feasible solution devised by the pytorch and thus you should be implementing `pytorch.optim.lr_scheduler`. Read more about this at other stackoverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60051713/13073020).

```
import torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR #step learning rate
scheduler = StepLR(optimizer, step_size=5, gamma=0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the comment above, @Alizera Omidi provided the answer.

There was a typo in the `params_group`, which is in fact `param_groups`